# Complicated string aggregation in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I am trying to complete a user journey path in BigQuery, but struggling with some complexities in the problem.

The original data looks like this for one user:

[image]

Each flattened quote represents a separate conversion (quote = conversion), so I need 3 separate user journeys.

Journey 1: "Paid Search - Pure Brand > Paid Search - Brand Hyrbid > Conversion"

Journey 2: "Paid Search - Pure Brand > Paid Search - Brand Hyrbid > Conversion" (*the user gets 2 quotes in one session, so journey 1 and journey 2 represent 2 separate conversions with the same path*)

Journey 3: "Paid Search - Pure Brand > Paid Search - Brand Hyrbid > Organic Search > Conversion"

It would also be fine if journey 3 ends up looking like:

Journey 3: "Paid Search - Pure Brand > Paid Search - Brand Hyrbid > Conversion > Organic Search > Conversion"

At the moment the closest I've got is:

[image]

The issue here is that although 2 of the conversions happen in visit number 2, they are listed here sequentially. This means that when you split by each conversion I end up with:

[image]

The fourth row isn't so much of an issue as it could be dropped, but I need row 2 and 3 to incorporate the previous visits.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
with table_a as (SELECT date, fullVisitorId, visitnumber, visitid, clientId, istruedirect, number_of_pages_in_session, flattened_quote, CASE WHEN flattened_quote IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(channel, channel, CONCAT(channel, " > Conversion abcdef10")) ELSE channel END as channel
FROM `source_table`
ORDER BY fullVisitorId, date, visitnumber),

table_b as (SELECT 
  fullVisitorId, 
  #flattened_quote,
  STRING_AGG(channel, ' > ') AS channelgrouping_path,
  ARRAY_AGG (
    STRUCT(flattened_quote)
  ) AS Values
FROM table_a
GROUP BY fullVisitorId)

select SPLIT(channelgrouping_path, "abcdef10") as split_into_each_journey
from table_b
where fullvisitorid = "1004040222968994500" # this is just using one visitor ID for validation, will be removed
```

If anyone has any tips on how to GROUP BY differently or something to achieve this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: if you can provide simplified example of input and expected output  - this will expedite getting answer - which I don't see any problem actually to provide when samples will be available

Comment: Can you explain better your input and the output you want to achieve?